# Theoritical amount of Sodium Bicarbonate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, stoichiometry

I have to find the theoretical amount of sodium bicarbonate. The steps I followed in order to produce it are:

1. 15g $\ce{NaCl}$ are added to a beaker. Then we add 87.5 mL of $\ce{NH3}(12M)$
2. We add 115g of dry ice(whose density is 1.5 g/mL)
3. Then the solid is taken with filtration and we rinse it first with 9mL of cold water and then with 6mL of acetone.

Then we put the solid in the oven. I know that the product after we take it off the oven will be sodium bicarbonate.
I believe that in order to find the theoretical amount of sodium bicarbonate I have to write down the reactions that are taking place.

$\ce{NaCl + NH_3 + CO_2 + H_2O → NH_4Cl + NaHCO_3}$

But I'm confused as to if there is another reaction where $\ce{NH_4Cl}$ and $\ce{NaHCO_3}$ react with water or acetone. Also, working with the stoichiometry of the reactions, from which reactant is it better to conclude about the moles of NaHCO3?

Comment: considering your second question, when looking at the reaction $\ce{2A + B -> AB + A}$, how much AB do you think you get? 1 or 2?

Comment: I get 1 AB. But we have to know the moles of A and B in order to see how much reacts from each and how much AB we will finally get.

Comment: yeah. So have you calculated how many moles you have of your reactants?

Comment: The moles of NaCl are 0.256, the moles of NH3  are 1.05. I'm confused about the moles of CO2(which is produced by the dry ice)

Comment: $\ce{CO_2}$ moles are *not* produced by dry ice. Dry ice *is* $\ce{CO_2}$.

You need 1 $\ce{NaCl}$ to get 1 $\ce{NaHCO_3}$, right? So if you have 0.256 mol of $\ce{Na}$, how much $\ce{NaHCO_3}$ could you theoretically synthesize (no losses, no by-products)?

Comment: Yes I didn't say it correctly, I meant that CO2 is dry ice. Theoretically we could synthesize o.256 mol of NaHCO3. But do we have to take into consideration the moles of NH3? Also, in order to fully conclude that the moles of NaHCO3 are 0.256, we should write the reactions between NH4Cl and NaHCO3 with water and acetone.

Comment: For the main reaction you need a 1:1 ratio of $\ce{Na}$ and $\ce{NH_3}$. How would you "take the moles of $\ce{NH_3}$ into consideration"??

Have you checked what reactions between your products and water & acetone can happen? What do you think could happen? Does it even matter? Have you done the reaction? How much bicarbonate have you got?

Comment: Since the moles of NH3 are 1.05 and the moles of NaCl are 0.256, it means that NH3 exceeds so my fault. I really don't know if they react with acetone, I just know that we used it in order to dry the solid.